Find pairs of wires incorrectly joined in opposite directions
Let's have a database model of wires (the ----- asciiart below) which are terminated on plugs (the * char). The plug can be either an endpoint of at most two wires which forms a linear path of arbitrary length or it is endpoint of single wire which means it is terminal plug of the path. Multiple linear paths (also called "lanes") might be bound together into board. Corresponding wires from parallel lanes at same level are identified by parallel_id. The number of lanes in a board might be one to unbounded.
Example:
board1
        P1  W1   P2  W2   P3  W3   P4
         *--------*--------*--------*
            p1       p2       p3
         *--------*--------*--------*
        P5  W4   P6  W5   P7  W6   P8

board2
        P9  W7   P10 W8   P11 W9   P16
         *--------*--------*--------*
            p4       p5       p6
         *--------*--------*--------*
        P13 W10  P14 W11  P15 W12  P12

board3
        P17 W13  P18 W14  P19
         *--------*--------*
            p7       p8

The database representation is given (of course simplified from real case):
with wire(board_id, parallel_id, wire_id, plug_l, plug_r) as (
  select 1, 1,  1,  1,  2 from dual union all
  select 1, 2,  2,  2,  3 from dual union all
  select 1, 3,  3,  3,  4 from dual union all
  select 1, 1,  4,  5,  6 from dual union all
  select 1, 2,  5,  6,  7 from dual union all
  select 1, 3,  6,  7,  8 from dual union all
  select 2, 4,  7,  9, 10 from dual union all
  select 2, 5,  8, 10, 11 from dual union all
  select 2, 6,  9, 11, 16 from dual union all
  select 2, 4, 10, 13, 14 from dual union all
  select 2, 5, 11, 14, 15 from dual union all
  select 2, 6, 12, 15, 12 from dual union all
  select 3, 7, 13, 17, 18 from dual union all
  select 3, 8, 14, 18, 19 from dual
)
select * from wire order by board_id, parallel_id, wire_id;

The task is to find all cases where board has exactly 2 lanes, there are two wires with same parallel_id and the ordering of their plug ids in some direction differs from ordering of next pair plug ids in the same direction. In the example above it is the direction to the right from parallel_id=5 because the plugs 11,15 impose sorting of lanes top-down while the plugs 12,16 impose sorting of lanes bottom-up.
(Real case is based on network inventory environment where plug ids to compare are actually some business numbers which are utilized in structured cabling - I reused ids for simplicity. We can also safely assume that wire.plug_% columns are not null and no plug is involved in three or more wires.)
The expected output is:



ERROR_MESSAGE




Invalid connection from (15,11) to (12,16)




Please [edit] the question and include a [MRE] with: a simple  explanation of the terms you are using and what "top-down" and "bottom-up" mean in terms of your data;  the expected output for your sample data. At the moment, it is not clear what question you want answering or why you expect a given solution.

From Oracle 12, you can use MATCH_RECOGNIZE to perform row-by-row pattern matching:
SELECT 'Invalid connection'
       ||' from ('||plug_l1||','||plug_l2||')'
       ||' to ('||plug_r1||','||plug_r2||')'
         AS error_message
FROM   wire
       MATCH_RECOGNIZE(
         PARTITION BY board_id, parallel_id
         ORDER BY     wire_id
         MEASURES 
           wire1.plug_l AS plug_l1,
           wire1.plug_r AS plug_r1,
           wire2.plug_l AS plug_l2,
           wire2.plug_r AS plug_r2
         PATTERN ( ^ wire1 wire2 $ )
         DEFINE
           wire2 AS (plug_l < PREV(plug_l) AND plug_r > PREV(plug_r))
                 OR (plug_l > PREV(plug_l) AND plug_r < PREV(plug_r))
       );

Or, in earlier versions:
SELECT 'Invalid connection'
       ||' from ('||plug_l1||','||plug_l2||')'
       ||' to ('||plug_r1||','||plug_r2||')'
         AS error_message
FROM   (
  SELECT board_id,
         parallel_id,
         wire_id,
         LAG(plug_l) OVER (PARTITION BY board_id, parallel_id ORDER BY wire_id)
          AS plug_l1,
         LAG(plug_r) OVER (PARTITION BY board_id, parallel_id ORDER BY wire_id)
          AS plug_r1,
         plug_l AS plug_l2,
         plug_r AS plug_r2,
         COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY board_id, parallel_id)
          AS num_wire
  FROM   wire
)
WHERE  num_wire = 2
AND    (  (plug_l1 < plug_l2 AND plug_r1 > plug_r2)
       OR (plug_l1 > plug_l2 AND plug_r1 < plug_r2)
       );

Which, for the sample data:
CREATE TABLE wire(board_id, parallel_id, wire_id, plug_l, plug_r) as
  select 1, 1,  1,  1,  2 from dual union all
  select 1, 2,  2,  2,  3 from dual union all
  select 1, 3,  3,  3,  4 from dual union all
  select 1, 1,  4,  5,  6 from dual union all
  select 1, 2,  5,  6,  7 from dual union all
  select 1, 3,  6,  7,  8 from dual union all
  select 2, 4,  7,  9, 10 from dual union all
  select 2, 5,  8, 10, 11 from dual union all
  select 2, 6,  9, 11, 16 from dual union all
  select 2, 4, 10, 13, 14 from dual union all
  select 2, 5, 11, 14, 15 from dual union all
  select 2, 6, 12, 15, 12 from dual union all
  select 3, 7, 13, 17, 18 from dual union all
  select 3, 8, 14, 18, 19 from dual

Both output:



ERROR_MESSAGE




Invalid connection from (11,15) to (16,12)



fiddle

One of possible solutions is interesting coding kata for pivot and unpivot SQL clauses.
The SQL query will be gradually built, let's assume the previous CTEs hold.
At first, lets measure number of lanes and introduce some discriminator column to distinguish wires from different lanes within same parallel_id. This is only auxiliary CTE.
,
paths as (
  select w.board_id, w.parallel_id, w.wire_id, w.plug_l, w.plug_r
       , count(*) over (partition by w.board_id, w.parallel_id) as cnt
       , row_number() over (partition by w.board_id, w.parallel_id order by null) as lane
  from wire w
)
select * from paths order by board_id, parallel_id, lane;

+--------+-----------+-------+------+------+---+----+
|BOARD_ID|PARALLEL_ID|WIRE_ID|PLUG_L|PLUG_R|CNT|LANE|
+--------+-----------+-------+------+------+---+----+
|1       |1          |1      |1     |2     |2  |1   |
|1       |1          |4      |5     |6     |2  |2   |
|1       |2          |2      |2     |3     |2  |1   |
|1       |2          |5      |6     |7     |2  |2   |
|1       |3          |3      |3     |4     |2  |1   |
|1       |3          |6      |7     |8     |2  |2   |
|2       |4          |7      |9     |10    |2  |1   |
|2       |4          |10     |13    |14    |2  |2   |
|2       |5          |11     |14    |15    |2  |1   |
|2       |5          |8      |10    |11    |2  |2   |
|2       |6          |9      |11    |16    |2  |1   |
|2       |6          |12     |15    |12    |2  |2   |
|3       |7          |13     |17    |18    |1  |1   |
|3       |8          |14     |18    |19    |1  |1   |
+--------+-----------+-------+------+------+---+----+

The first problem of given data representation is that we store data per wire while we need to process data per direction of particular couple of wires. Hence at first we must get rid of plug_l, plug_r columns. These columns become rows with single column plug_id and discriminator column for direction. Removing multiple usually similarly named columns in favor of less columns and discriminator is suitable use case for unpivot clause:
,
transposed as (
  select *
  from paths
  unpivot (plug_id for direction in (plug_l as 'L', plug_r as 'R'))
)
select * from transposed order by board_id, parallel_id, direction;

+--------+-----------+-------+---+----+---------+-------+
|BOARD_ID|PARALLEL_ID|WIRE_ID|CNT|LANE|DIRECTION|PLUG_ID|
+--------+-----------+-------+---+----+---------+-------+
|1       |1          |1      |2  |1   |L        |1      |
|1       |1          |4      |2  |2   |L        |5      |
|1       |1          |1      |2  |1   |R        |2      |
|1       |1          |4      |2  |2   |R        |6      |
|1       |2          |2      |2  |1   |L        |2      |
|1       |2          |5      |2  |2   |L        |6      |
|1       |2          |5      |2  |2   |R        |7      |
|1       |2          |2      |2  |1   |R        |3      |
|1       |3          |3      |2  |1   |L        |3      |
|1       |3          |6      |2  |2   |L        |7      |
|1       |3          |3      |2  |1   |R        |4      |
|1       |3          |6      |2  |2   |R        |8      |
|2       |4          |10     |2  |2   |L        |13     |
|2       |4          |7      |2  |1   |L        |9      |
|2       |4          |7      |2  |1   |R        |10     |
|2       |4          |10     |2  |2   |R        |14     |
|2       |5          |11     |2  |1   |L        |14     |
|2       |5          |8      |2  |2   |L        |10     |
|2       |5          |11     |2  |1   |R        |15     |
|2       |5          |8      |2  |2   |R        |11     |
|2       |6          |9      |2  |1   |L        |11     |
|2       |6          |12     |2  |2   |L        |15     |
|2       |6          |9      |2  |1   |R        |16     |
|2       |6          |12     |2  |2   |R        |12     |
|3       |7          |13     |1  |1   |L        |17     |
|3       |7          |13     |1  |1   |R        |18     |
|3       |8          |14     |1  |1   |L        |18     |
|3       |8          |14     |1  |1   |R        |19     |
+--------+-----------+-------+---+----+---------+-------+

Now we have to weave untangled data back. We want to take two rows for same board_id, parallel_id and direction. Obviously they differ in lane, wire_id and plug_id. Let's make two id columns from each of them, distinguished by lane. Making more columns and melting down the discriminator column values into new columns' names is reverse process to that one in previous paragraph hence the pivot clause comes handy (note it can even be part of same SQL statement without need for additional CTE):
-- caution: this paragraph rewrites (rather than appends) the CTE from last paragraph
,
transposed as (
  select *
  from paths
  unpivot (plug_id for direction in (plug_l as 'L', plug_r as 'R'))
  pivot (max(wire_id) as wire_id, max(plug_id) as plug_id for lane in (1 as l1, 2 as l2))
  where cnt = 2
)
select * from transposed order by board_id, parallel_id, direction;

+--------+-----------+---+---------+----------+----------+----------+----------+
|BOARD_ID|PARALLEL_ID|CNT|DIRECTION|L1_WIRE_ID|L1_PLUG_ID|L2_WIRE_ID|L2_PLUG_ID|
+--------+-----------+---+---------+----------+----------+----------+----------+
|1       |1          |2  |L        |1         |1         |4         |5         |
|1       |1          |2  |R        |1         |2         |4         |6         |
|1       |2          |2  |L        |2         |2         |5         |6         |
|1       |2          |2  |R        |2         |3         |5         |7         |
|1       |3          |2  |L        |3         |3         |6         |7         |
|1       |3          |2  |R        |3         |4         |6         |8         |
|2       |4          |2  |L        |7         |9         |10        |13        |
|2       |4          |2  |R        |7         |10        |10        |14        |
|2       |5          |2  |L        |11        |14        |8         |10        |
|2       |5          |2  |R        |11        |15        |8         |11        |
|2       |6          |2  |L        |9         |11        |12        |15        |
|2       |6          |2  |R        |9         |16        |12        |12        |
+--------+-----------+---+---------+----------+----------+----------+----------+

(Side note on filtering boards of width 2: The condition is simple - we want to take only rows with cnt=2 from the paths CTE and also hide the column since it is unnecessary thereafter. There are several possibilities:

insert special CTE between:
...
filtered as (
  select board_id, parallel_id, wire_id, plug_l, plug_r, lane
  from paths
  where cnt != 2
)
, transposed as (... from filtered ...) ...

(Unfortunately the condition can't be in where clause of paths CTE because cnt is computed in window function and Oracle does not support the qualify clause.)
filter it out in transposed CTE like in example. Hiding column will be done later.
for comparison against constant the following trick is also possible:
pivot ... for (lane,cnt) in ((1,2) as l1, (2,2) as l2))

This utilizes the fact that columns in for clause are automatically hidden. However the rows for cnt != 2 are still present with null values hence additional where l1_wire_id is not null condition is necessary anyway.)

Profit! Now we have data in proper format - each row represents one side of pair of wires. With such data it is simple to compose query solving specified task. Whole SQL follows:
with wire(board_id, parallel_id, wire_id, plug_l, plug_r) as (
  select 1, 1,  1,  1,  2 from dual union all
  select 1, 2,  2,  2,  3 from dual union all
  select 1, 3,  3,  3,  4 from dual union all
  select 1, 1,  4,  5,  6 from dual union all
  select 1, 2,  5,  6,  7 from dual union all
  select 1, 3,  6,  7,  8 from dual union all
  select 2, 4,  7,  9, 10 from dual union all
  select 2, 5,  8, 10, 11 from dual union all
  select 2, 6,  9, 11, 16 from dual union all
  select 2, 4, 10, 13, 14 from dual union all
  select 2, 5, 11, 14, 15 from dual union all
  select 2, 6, 12, 15, 12 from dual union all
  select 3, 7, 13, 17, 18 from dual union all
  select 3, 8, 14, 18, 19 from dual union all
  select null,null,null,null,null from dual where 0=1
)
--select * from wire order by board_id, parallel_id, wire_id;
,
paths as (
  select w.board_id, w.parallel_id, w.wire_id, w.plug_l, w.plug_r
       , count(*) over (partition by w.board_id, w.parallel_id) as cnt
       , row_number() over (partition by w.board_id, w.parallel_id order by null) as lane
  from wire w
)
--select * from paths order by board_id, parallel_id, lane;
,
transposed as (
  select *
  from paths
  unpivot (plug_id for direction in (plug_l as 'L', plug_r as 'R'))-- order by board_id, parallel_id, lane;
  pivot (max(wire_id) as wire_id, max(plug_id) as plug_id for lane in (1 as l1, 2 as l2))
  where cnt = 2
)
--select * from transposed order by board_id, parallel_id, direction;
,
nextplug as (
  select t.l1_wire_id as start_wire_1, t.l1_plug_id as start_plug_1, w1.wire_id as next_wire_1, case t.l1_plug_id when w1.plug_l then w1.plug_r else w1.plug_l end as next_plug_1
       , t.l2_wire_id as start_wire_2, t.l2_plug_id as start_plug_2, w2.wire_id as next_wire_2, case t.l2_plug_id when w2.plug_l then w2.plug_r else w2.plug_l end as next_plug_2
  from transposed t
  join wire       w1 on t.l1_plug_id in (w1.plug_l, w1.plug_r) and t.l1_wire_id != w1.wire_id
  join wire       w2 on t.l2_plug_id in (w2.plug_l, w2.plug_r) and t.l2_wire_id != w2.wire_id
)
select 'Invalid connection from (' || start_plug_1 || ',' || start_plug_2 || ') to (' || next_plug_1 || ',' || next_plug_2 || ')' as error_message
from nextplug
where sign(start_plug_1 - start_plug_2) != sign(next_plug_1 - next_plug_2);

+------------------------------------------+
|ERROR_MESSAGE                             |
+------------------------------------------+
|Invalid connection from (15,11) to (12,16)|
+------------------------------------------+


Using order by null does not guarantee any particular ordering so when you run the query you are likely to find that the ROW_NUMBER is assigned randomly and will change between executions. Therefore, your assigned lanes are not guaranteed to be in that order once you put the data into a table.
